# atom - remote sync plugin download after remote change

Tags: php, remote-access, atom-editor

I am using atom editor, remote-sync plugin so that after every change I make right in the editor it will be updated automatically.
That is working perfectly and it's a nice feature. I want to know if there is a way that every remote change will be downloaded to my local version. They have a watch for files.

```
"watch":[
  "/css/styles.css",
  "/index.html"
 ]
```

I want to know if there is a possible way to watch for the whole folder so that every change is tracked.

Comment: Does simply adding "/" work? I use remote-sync and have not set any watch files. I have "uploadOnSave" set to true, and it seems to upload the files regardless of whether they are in the "watch" array.

Comment: The issue is not uploading. The issue is downloading the change on the hosted version